# How i can remove the argument or arguments from the procedure call

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I run my code I get a notification that

> Public readonly property Count as integer has no parameters and it's
>   return type cannot be indexed.

How can I fix this?

```
Public Sub Connect(userName As String)
    Dim id = Context.ConnectionId


    If ConnectedUsers.Count(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id) = 0 Then
        ConnectedUsers.Add(New UserDetail() With { _
            Key .ConnectionId = id, _
            Key .UserName = userName _
        })

        ' send to caller
        Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage)

        ' send to all except caller client

        Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like your `ConnectedUsers` has a ReadOnly Property named count and you are trying to use it as an extension method

Comment: no my property named ConnectionId()   Shared ConnectedUsers As New List(Of UserDetail)()
        Shared CurrentMessage As New List(Of MessageDetail)()

Comment: yes. The count property on `List(of T)` is  `Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer`.  You are trying to pass a lambda to it.  Use `.Where().ToArray().Count`

Comment: thanks but i got an you argument say overload resolution failed no accessible 'where' accepts these numbers of arguments i'm sorry i'm not that good in vb.net i use c# but i'm trying to help my friend

Comment: pass the lambda to the where (just like in C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your If statement as suggested by Plutonix. But he was not giving you the full code:

```
If ConnectedUsers.Where(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id).Count() = 0 Then
```

When you access `Count` on the `List` type, it's only a property, not a method. The `Where` extension method allows you to pass in the lambda check, and returns you a different object that has a `Count` method (not property) like the one you were expecting to see.